# Why I can't use justify-content property with grid?

Tags: css

I want to align image right like banner. But when I use grid and justify-content:end, images align row.
I watched chrome inspector, it said use flex.
Why grid can't use justify-content?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#iconbanner {
  display: grid;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="iconbanner">
  <img src="blog.png" class="icon">
  <img src="youtube.png" class="icon">
  <img src="instagram.png" class="icon">
</div>
```

I tried grid and justify-contet:end; but cant' align images column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (I added a `gap` between images) :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#iconbanner {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="iconbanner">
  <img src="blog.png" class="icon">
  <img src="youtube.png" class="icon">
  <img src="instagram.png" class="icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a grid, use justify-items instead of justify-content.